# Acceptor thread versus Selector thread

Tags: asynchronous, nio, glassfish-3, nonblocking, grizzly

In the context of NIO based WebServer's (Grizzly to be specific), is the terminology "Acceptor Thread" and "Selector Thread" interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

As per this doc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/gcsvs/index.html

Acceptor threads are  threads used to serve OP_ACCEPT (socket.accept())
Selector Threads are threads used to  handing OP_READ operations.

So No , they are not interchangeable